# Finite almost everywhere for a generic function in $L^1$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and we consider a measurable positive function $f\colon X\to[0,+\infty]$. I already proved that if the Lebesgue integral of $f$ on $X$ is finite, that is $$\int_X f\;\text{d}\mu<+\infty,$$ then $\mu(\{f=+\infty\})=0$, that is $f$ is finite almost everywhere.

Now, let $f\colon X\to [-\infty, +\infty]$ an $\mu$- integrable function, that is $$\int_Xf_+\;\text{d}\mu<+\infty\quad\int_Xf_-\;\text{d}\mu<+\infty,$$ then $$\int_X|f|\;\text{d}\mu=\int_X(f_++f_-)\;\text{d}\mu<\infty,$$
and therefore $|f|$ is finite ae, so is a measurable positive function.

From this can I conclude that $f$ itself is finite almost everywhere?

**Notation.**

$f_+:=\max\{f(x),0\}$ and $f_-:=\max\{-f(x),0\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $|f|$ is finite a.e. then so too is $f$, because any point where $f$ is infinite would force $|f|$ to be infinite as well.